# How to query multiple object query in jitterbit dataloader

Tags: jitterbit

I am using jitterbit dataloader want to integrate(send data from sql to salesforce) sql to salesforce.

In jitterbit i had quered one object(account) and able to send data from sql to salesforce.

But i am having 2 objects account with 2 queries and contact with name as one common field.

select name from account ;
select name from contact;-->are 2 queries but i want to join all two of them and send all details

how to join 2 queries in jitterbit dataloader and update it in 2 objects sfdc

Answer (score 2):

- If you are on a trial (non-commercial), use JDBC driver and write a manual Sql statement to query multiple objects simultaneously.
- In a commercial version, you can either write manual sql statements or in the wizard you can pick multiple objects.
- If you are using a commercial trial version, you can get a service engineer to help you. Send email to support@jitterbit.com

Refer [this](https://getsatisfaction.com/dataloader/topics/how_to_use_sql_joins_in_jitterbit_data_loader) official Jitteribt forum link for details.